# OS X: using the keyboard to select an option in a message window / box?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm still a new Mac owner, and I've struggled with the message windows / boxes / popups that sometimes appear and ask me to choose an option, like "save" "don't save" and "cancel" in TextEdit's case. I noticed I can't use the arrow keys to navigate these buttons, but pressing Enter will choose the default option and ESC will choose the "cancel" option. Is there any way to control this with the keyboard? Or are the Apple engineers forcing me to use a mouse / trackpad?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is really annoying I can tell, but you can tab through dialog boxes.

Go to "System Preferences" > "Keyboard & Shrotcuts".

At the very bottom there will be an option saying about "full keyboard access". Check the radio button that says “All Controls” and here you go

Comment: Then the <Tab> key helps you to choose the button you want, and <Spacebar> to validate your choice.

Comment: Oh this is just awesome. Thanks! What a relief!

Comment: It is "Keyboard Navigation" in Sonama version of Mac OS. Just turn it on.

Answer (score 4):

Most applications will also accept some keyboard commands for those dialog boxes:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> for Cancel
- <kbd>Return</kbd> for the default (blue) button (usually Save)
- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for Don't Save.

Comment: Others: sometimes don't save is Command+Delete rather than Command-D; Command+period is another cancel option; Command+S is often save: see  http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/21/save-sheet-shortcuts-in-lion/

Answer (score 0):

Press enter for the highlighted button in a message dialog and space for the outlined one. Or press escape to abort/cancel.

Answer (score 0):

In Sonoma release, turn on "Keyboard navigation" in keyboard shortcuts. And, then use tab to navigate the buttons. Press space bar to select.

[image]