# How can I use the keyboard to navigate dialog boxes in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, osx-lion, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X: using the keyboard to select an option in a message window / box?](https://superuser.com/questions/167833/os-x-using-the-keyboard-to-select-an-option-in-a-message-window-box)

On Snow Leopard 10.6 I used to be able to use tab and space to navigate between buttons and select one. I looked through the Accessibility preference pane and I have the "enable access for assistive devices" enabled, and everything else looks good - it is factory default.

Two examples of dialogs I can no longer navigate with tab / space:

[image: textmate dialog]

[image: photoshop dialog]

Comment: Don't know about the setting in Lion, but for these dialogues, pressing `Cmd-D` results in `Don't Save`.

Comment: -1 *This question does not show any research effort*. I generally like your questions and enjoy answering them, but this one could have been solved with half a minute of research.

Comment: @DanielBeck Un -1'd. This is still a common problem other people might search for.

Comment: @Lri Sure if you think the question is worth it. [I'd go with the top hit when searching for "osx dialog keyboard" on the site](http://superuser.com/questions/167833/os-x-using-the-keyboard-to-select-an-option-in-a-message-window-box) instead.

Comment: Holy huge shadows Batman!

Comment: @DanielBeck - I can see why you -1'd it. I immediately assumed that it was Lion since it worked fine on OS X and Lion has done some other stuff I'm not fond of. Sorry. FWIW I did search the site before posting but was looking for things relative to lion. Perhaps this can help others.

Comment: Un -1ing because I typed in "os x lion dialog box" into google and came across this as my first hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability to <kbd>Tab</kbd> through all controls is not and has never been controlled by the “Enable access for assistive devices” setting (which is for enabling third-party software only).

It is controlled through the setting **System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Full Keyboard Access**:

[image: “Full Keyboard Access: In windows and dialogs, press Tab to move keyboard focus between: • Text boxes and lists only • All controls Press Control+F7 to change this setting.”]